# How do I determine my drive's file format?

Tags: ext4, format

How do I find out what format my hard drive is in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find out, just run disk utility to find out the drive format type.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

To find out what type of file system the currently mounted drive is running use this command:

```
df -T
```

For more on the "df" tool you can visit the man page via:

```
man df
```

(press q to exit)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Disk Utility` and click on the drive you are interested in.  A block diagram will be displayed and labels will indicate the format type.